# Dealing cards in a card game, players always receive one card less?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a card game but when I deal the cards, every player always gets one less than they should. For example, if I have 4 players, they will each get 12 instead of 13 cards.
Here is my code

```
for (int j = 0; j < 52; j=j + numberOfPlayers){



    for (int i=0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){

      playerspiles[i].bottom(deck[x]); 


   }
}
```

Comment: Your edit makes no sense; ``j`.` increase by ``2 * numOfPlayers`` now.

Answer (score 5):

Use a better approach:

```
for(int j=0;j<52;j++){
  playerspiles[j%numOfPlayers].addToBottom(deck[j]);
}
```

What this does is it uses modular arithmetic/wrap around arithmetic to evenly distribute the cards (this is done using the % operator).

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html

Comment: This worked perfectly, but would you mind explaining how you came up with this please?

Comment: thank you  for going above and beyond! I understand what the modulo operator does I was just a little overwhelmed that it was able to replace all my code with one line!

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing cards, not players.

```
 // First recipient
 int playerId = 0;

 // Deal from the deck, until you run out of cards.
 for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
 {
     playerspiles[playerId].addToBottom(deck[i]);

     // Next recipient (playerId is between 0 and numberOfPlayers-1)
     playerId = (playerId + 1) % numberOfPlayers;
 }

 // Print each player's hand 
 for (int p = 0; p < numberOfPlayers; p++)
 {
     PrintHand(playerspiles[p]);
 }
```